# Mysterious extra 100GB of hard drive space taken up

Tags: finder, hard-drive, storage, disk-space, macos

I have a 250GB SSD hard drive on my Mac.

Last time I checked the remaining space was about a week ago when I removed Bootcamp and free'd up an extra 50GB of space. This left me with around 150GB space remaining.

I've just checked today and only have 60GB free!

I've also instealled 'Clean my Mac' and checked for junk files, but it only found 9GB worth.

The only real folders I can think of that take up room are my Dropbox folder (which contains **all** of my files, at least all those that I'm aware of) and my Applications folder.

Both of those folders combined only take up 50GB amount of space according to Finder.

I read that the 'Library/Caches' folder can take up a lot of space there, but only found 10GB (possibly what was found my CleanMyMac)

I've also emptied my trash.

Also I read on another forum about running the following command in Terminal:

```
~ % sudo rm -r /System/Library/Caches
```

But I just get the following error:

> rm: /System/Library/Caches: Read-only file system

I can't even think of where else to look for what could be taking up all this room?

Comment: that worked nicely thank you so much! turns out I totally forgot I sync'd a 75GB folder on Dropbox! for some reason that wasn't registering in Finder when I checked the size of the folder, but after checking In DaisyDisk everything seems to be showing properly... maybe time to unsync that folder!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Thanks for letting us know. :)

Comment: I don't suppose you have any idea why my Finder wasn't displaying the correct folder size for my Dropbox at all? (until now anyway)... maybe that's for a separate question though

Comment: I really don't know - haven't used Dropbox in years. Maybe try a new question, but it might be as simple as "it didn't get around to adding up the numbers yet". Some structures don't calculate until you look at them - Heisenberg-style ;)

Comment: I've just found that, when unsync'ing the folder, that Finder didn't update again straight away. Then I found a hidden Dropbox cache folder which is apparently stored for 3 days. Think that might have something to do with it